# static singleton object and their scopes

Tags: c#

Supposing that I have declared a singleton `Single` and I would like to initialize `S` for use in classes like this

```
public class A
{
  public Single s=Single.Instance;
  // methods
}
```

I have multiple classes like A (B,C,D, etc). and also containing the line `public Single s=Single.Instance`

Is this a bad design ? multiple singletons exist.
Sorry for a basic question but when `s` is initialized and how long it will live.

Comment: When it is initialized depends on how it is initialized.. you haven't shown that. `static` objects are guaranteed to be initialized prior to any access of the type that wraps them.. when that is is undetermined. `static` objects live for the life of an AppDomain.

Comment: If Single.Instance is correctly implemented as singleton, then you only ever have 1 instance of the singleton but multiple references to that one instance. That is not a bad design per se.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN also suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) using SingletonClass.Instance as property to get the static
object of singletor class, when this is done, their will be only one object (not multiple)
as the Instance property of Singleton class would ensure that

as far as the singleton object is not disposed, it will be available to any class